# Texture & Quad Drawing Wrong, Android OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I, for the life of me, am unable to get a simple sprite drawing to screen using OpenGL ES and Java. Graphics programming is definitely my weak spot, and my rustiness with OpenGL isn't helping, what so ever.

**What I'm trying to do**

Use a quad class to render a textured quad to the screen

**What I've tried**

I was using glDrawTexfOES and everything was dandy. But, upon some inspection, I realized that I wouldn't be able to use the translations and rotations I would require to build a more robust system; so, I decided to go for a textured quad, as, a long time ago, I'd done just that in college.

**The Issue**

My texture ends up taking the entire screen and not being mapped correctly, it makes me somewhat grumpy. I was hoping I could get some eyes on my code and some professional opinions.

**The Result**

Should be this:

[image: Correct Image]

But is this:

[image: Incorrect Image]

Thank you so much, in advance!

My Quad class:

```
public class Quad
{
    private float _Vertices[] = 
        {
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // Top left
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom left
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // Bottom right
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   // Top right
        };

    private float _TextureCoords[] = 
        { 
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f
        };

    private FloatBuffer _VertexBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer _IndexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer _TextureBuffer;

    private short[] _Indices = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

    public Quad()
    {
        Setup();
    }

    public void Setup()
    {
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( _Vertices.length * 4 );
        vbb.order( ByteOrder.nativeOrder() );

        _VertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        _VertexBuffer.put( _Vertices );
        _VertexBuffer.position( 0 );

        ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( _Indices.length * 2 );
        ibb.order( ByteOrder.nativeOrder() );

        _IndexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();

        _IndexBuffer.put( _Indices );
        _IndexBuffer.position( 0 );

        ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( _TextureCoords.length * 4 );
        tbb.order( ByteOrder.nativeOrder() );

        _TextureBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
        _TextureBuffer.put( _TextureCoords );
        _TextureBuffer.position( 0 );
    }

    public void Draw( GL10 gl, Texture texture )
    {               
        gl.glBindTexture( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getID() );
        gl.glTexCoordPointer( 2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _TextureBuffer );

        gl.glVertexPointer( 3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _VertexBuffer );
        gl.glDrawElements( GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, _Indices.length,
                GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, _IndexBuffer );
    }
}
```

My renderer:

```
public class FoxRenderer implements Renderer
{
private Context _Context;
private Quad _Quad;

private int _Width;
private int _Height;

public FoxRenderer( Context context, Game game )
{
    // Assignment
    _Context = context;
    _Game = game;

    _Quad = new Quad();
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    _Quad.Draw( gl, _Game.getGameData().TextureSystem.GetTexture( "buddha") );
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
{
    _Width = width;
    _Height = height;

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
{
    // Initialize various OpenGL elements
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);

    gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Disabling certain elements for performance
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);

    // Stuff for rendering quads
    gl.glFrontFace( GL10.GL_CCW );
    gl.glEnable( GL10.GL_CULL_FACE );
    gl.glCullFace( GL10.GL_BACK );

    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    gl.glEnableClientState( GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
gl.glEnableClientState( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );
}
}
```

And, just in case, my texture loading:

```
public void LoadTexture( String name, int resource )
{
    Texture texture = new Texture();

    // LOADING TEXTURE CODE
    int[] temp = new int[ 1 ];

    _GL10.glGenTextures( 1, temp, 0 );

    // Get newly generated OpenGL texture ID and bind it and store in our texture class
    int id = temp[ 0 ];
    _GL10.glBindTexture( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id );
    texture.setID( id );

    _GL10.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
    _GL10.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
    _GL10.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT );
    _GL10.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT );
    _GL10.glTexEnvf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE );

    // Load actual resource into bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( _Context.getResources(), resource );

    // Not 100% sure what this does
    GLUtils.texImage2D( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0 );

    texture.setWidth( bitmap.getWidth() );
    texture.setHeight( bitmap.getHeight() );

    _Map.put( name, texture );

    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem with the help of a graphics engineer I work with. Just needed to change my onSurfaceChanged:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
{
    _Width = width;
    _Height = height;

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrthof(0.0f, width, height, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Also changed to clock-wise winding:

```
gl.glFrontFace( GL10.GL_CW );
```

And changed my vertices:

```
private static float _Vertices[] = 
{
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,   
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,  
};
```

And now everything works the way I want, including having it act like screen-space in most engines (positive Y down).

Comment: Haha, I plan to :) I just have to wait 8 more hours, apparently, before I can accept my own answer. Thank you for all of the help, though! It was greatly appreciated!